# SQL query customized output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below query:

```
   select 'my.MYNAME=' + name  from hostnames;

   my.MYNAME=abc
   my.MYNAME=xyz
   my.MYNAME=poi
```

The query is dynamic is gives3 result, it may give more result depending upon data.

I need following output:

```
my.MYNAME1=abc
my.MYNAME2=xyz
my.MYNAME3=poi
```

Numbers appending to MYNAME according to result it gives.

I have tried

```
select 'my.MYNAME={c}' + name  from hostnames where (select count(*) as c from name);
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Just append `ROWNUM` after `MYNAME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about it is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('my.MYNAME',ROWNUM),'='), name) FROM hostnames
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0658/2)

Comment: It's a bit simpler and easier to follow [with the concatenation operator](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0658/3)?

Comment: Hi Alex, I agree it is simpler but according to [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm#i997789) When moving SQL script files between systems having different character sets, such as between ASCII and EBCDIC, vertical bars might not be translated into the vertical bar required by the target Oracle Database environment.